# How to simplify a path composed of multiple bezier curves?

Tags: geometry, bezier

I have a path composed of multiple cubic bezier curves, and I need to simplify it to a smoother path.

[image: paths]

This is basically what Inkscape's Simplify(Ctrl+L) algorithm does, when applying it multiple times.

In the above example, I applied the `simplify` algorithm until the number of nodes became `< 10`. This is not mandatory though, and any number of nodes/thresholding metric is acceptable, as long as it's not unbearably slow.

Following is both paths from this example, in SVG Syntax:

```
Original path (black):
m 14550,8173.5 c 0,5 -7,10 -16,10 -20,0 -44,24 -44,44 0,19 -16,21 -23,3 -2,-6 -8,-8 -13,-4 -5,4 -2,13 6,18 11,8 12,12 3,16 -7,2 -13,17 -13,33 0,16 -6,31 -12,33 -10,4 -9,8 2,16 13,10 13,12 0,22 -11,8 -12,12 -2,16 6,2 12,11 12,20 0,19 24,43 43,43 9,0 18,6 21,12 5,10 7,10 12,0 3,-6 19,-12 35,-12 16,0 29,-5 29,-10 0,-6 9,-10 20,-10 13,0 20,-7 20,-20 0,-11 5,-20 10,-20 6,0 10,-5 10,-10 0,-6 -9,-10 -20,-10 -13,0 -20,7 -20,20 0,15 -7,20 -29,20 -16,0 -32,6 -35,12 -5,10 -7,10 -12,0 -3,-6 -14,-12 -24,-12 -10,0 -20,6 -23,12 -2,7 -8,9 -13,5 -5,-4 -2,-13 6,-18 11,-8 12,-12 3,-16 -7,-2 -13,-18 -13,-34 0,-29 0,-29 59,-29 38,0 61,4 64,12 4,10 8,9 16,-2 9,-13 12,-13 20,-1 8,12 12,12 25,-2 17,-17 22,-87 6,-87 -5,0 -10,-7 -10,-16 0,-23 -25,-44 -54,-44 -14,0 -26,-5 -26,-10 0,-6 -4,-10 -10,-10 -5,0 -10,4 -10,10 m 20,20 c 0,5 7,10 16,10 20,0 44,24 44,43 0,9 5,17 12,19 8,3 2,15 -15,32 l -28,28 -20,-23 c -17,-20 -22,-21 -30,-9 -8,13 -10,13 -20,0 -8,-11 -12,-12 -16,-3 -8,20 -23,15 -23,-7 0,-11 5,-20 10,-20 6,0 10,-7 10,-15 0,-16 39,-63 53,-64 4,-1 7,3 7,9 m -40,240 c 0,5 -4,10 -10,10 -5,0 -10,-5 -10,-10 0,-6 5,-10 10,-10 6,0 10,4 10,10

Simplified path (red):
m 14550,8173.5 c -87.258,33.0594 -133.146,148.0519 -100.308,233.0182 28.598,79.3143 205.987,42.2193 169.477,-27.3586 -37.609,79.4541 -211.748,14.7616 -116.882,-53.3781 65.16,23.4014 214.495,3.3059 154.09,-94.6746 -20.611,-36.676 -63.348,-64.0056 -106.377,-57.6069 z m 20,20 c 97.756,2.0053 70.654,166.2739 -23.471,106.0693 -77.428,-5.092 -32.934,-112.5198 23.471,-106.0693 z m -40,240 c -21.559,21.7572 -1.859,-30.1121 0,0 z
```

Are there any known algorithms for this problem?

(Sorry about not having any code. I'm using python and [svgpathtools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svgpathtools/1.3.1). Having said that, this is not a [python](/questions/tagged/python) question: I'm accepting solutions in any language (or even just pseudocode!)

I navigated through Inkscape's source code, but the implementation of the algorithm there is huge, and seems strongly coupled with Inkscape's internals.

Comment: For fun, and insight, also draw the on-curve and off-curve points, both before and after, because I don't think you need us for this: just drawn each step with the points included so you see how they move, and I'm pretty sure that'll almost instantly show you what you need to write in terms of code to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure if Inkscape uses this method, I believe what you are looking for is called "[curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting)", which is the process of constructing a curve, or mathematical function, that has the best fit to a series of data points, possibly subject to constraints.

[image: curve fitting demo]

**For implementation, look at:**

1. Philip J. Schneider's [FitCurves.c](https://github.com/erich666/GraphicsGems/blob/master/gems/FitCurves.c)
2. C library [ideasman42/curve-fit-nd](https://github.com/ideasman42/curve-fit-nd)
3. Rust library [ideasman42/raster-retrace](https://github.com/ideasman42/raster-retrace)

[image]